# Why doesn't reactive({ }) take a dependency on a changing input?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

In the below code for a Shiny app, I am expecting the print line to execute when the user clicks on a new row in the datatable. When I do this, the textOutput updates with the selected row via input$table_rows_selected as expected. But why does change <- reactive({ }) not take a dependency on changes to input$table_rows_selected and trigger the print message?

I see that it works with observe({}) but ultimately I want to use a value that reactive returns in different places (e.g here return and return2).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

     DT::DTOutput("table"),
     
     textOutput("selected"),
     
     textOutput("return"),
     
     textOutput("return2")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)
    }, selection = 'single')
    
    
    output$selected <- renderText({
        input$table_rows_selected
    })
    
    change <- reactive({
        input$table_rows_selected
        print("it changed!")
        "return"
    })
    
    output$return <- renderText({
        isolate(change())
    })
    
    output$return2 <- renderText({
        paste0(isolate(change()), "_2")
    })
    
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems:

- a `reactive` is just a function, therefore its return value is the last value generated in the `reactive` -> you need to put `input$table_rows_selected` last
- the `isolate(change())` means that `reactives` don't have a dependency on `input$table_rows_selected` -> remove the `isolate`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  DT::DTOutput("table"),
  
  textOutput("selected"),
  
  textOutput("return"),
  
  textOutput("return2")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)
  }, selection = 'single')
  
  
  output$selected <- renderText({
    input$table_rows_selected
  })
  
  change <- reactive({
    print("it changed!")
    input$table_rows_selected
  })
  
  output$return <- renderText({
    change()
  })
  
  output$return2 <- renderText({
    paste0(change(), "_2")
  })
  
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```